# Como configurar o timezone no REPL Clojure?

Tags: timezone, intellij, clojure

Como configurar o REPL com o timezone correto?

Ao executar uma query num banco postgres através de um REPL os campos data estão com fuso horário UTC quero configurá-lo para America/Sao_Paulo.

No REPL do Intellij eu tentei o seguinte:

- Configurar o arquivo idea.vmoptions (do intellij) com o parâmetro `-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo`
- Adicionar `:jvm-opts ["-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo"]` no `project.clj`
- Adicionar `-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo` na configuração do REPL pelo intellij
- `export JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo:$JAVA_OPTS"` no arquivo `~/.zshrc`

e no REPL Leiningen:

- Adicionar `:jvm-opts ["-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo"]` no `project.clj`
- `export JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo:$JAVA_OPTS"` no arquivo `~/.zshrc`
  Nada surtiu efeito!

Exemplo

```
(ns experiments
  (:require [next.jdbc :as jdbc]))

(def db
  {:dbtype   "postgres"
   :dbname   "<dbname>"
   :host     "<host>"
   :port     5432
   :user     "<user>"
   :password "<pass>"})

(def ds (jdbc/get-datasource db))

(jdbc/execute! ds ["select current_timestamp"])
```

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, o timestamp que você está pegando não tem relação com o REPL, Clojure ou IntelliJ. O `current_timestamp` é um retorno do Postgres que, por padrão, retorna UTC. Você provavelmente teria que fazer alguma coisa parecida com isso: `SELECT current_timestamp::timestamp at time zone 'UTC';`

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão a **JVM** pega o timezone da variável de ambiente `TZ`

```bash
export TZ="America/Sao_Paulo"
```

Caso não queira declarar a variável de ambiente por algum motivo você pode passar via opts da JVM, como você comentou na pergunta:

```
-Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo
```

No seu exemplo você executa a consulta `(jdbc/execute! ds ["select current_timestamp"])`, a função `current_timestamp` do PostgreSQL pega a data/hora local do servidor que esta rodando o banco de dados, não do servidor de aplicação, ou seja, *provavelmente o problema de **"timezone"** não é na JVM e sim no servidor de banco de dados.*